# OpenCV edit single band and remerge

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb

I have an image which I have split into its three separate channels (b,g,r). I want to manipulate just the red band and then remerge to blue and green band to recompose image. I keep getting a sig abort in my function however. the `RBandSlider` refers to a global int used for a trackbar which is defaulted to 1. Almost positive the issue is within the `ImageEnhancement` function.

Do I need to define `redBandsAdjsuted` as something else or am I not grabbing the pixel local and rewriting it correctly?

```
Mat ImageEnhancement(Mat band){
Mat adjustedBand;
Scalar mean, std;
meanStdDev(band, mean , std);
int pixel,temp;
for(int i = 0; i < band.rows;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < band.cols;j++){
        //extract pixel
        pixel = band.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        //pixel greater than mean
        if ( pixel > mean[0]){
            temp = (255);
            adjustedBand.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = temp;
        }
        else{
            temp = 0;
            adjustedBand.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = temp ;
        }
    }
}
return adjustedBand;
}


Mat Bands[3],merged,redBandsAdjusted(image.cols,image.rows,CV_8UC1),result;
split(image, Bands);

//loop the echancement adjustment
while(true){


    //adjust red band and merge
    redBandsAdjusted = ImageEnhancement(Bands[2]);
    vector<Mat> channels = {Bands[0],Bands[1],redBandsAdjusted};
    merge(channels,merged);

}
```

Comment: Try using the debugger. Break where you calculate the mean and check it. Then break where you adjust each pixel and see if you are not handling saturated values correctly or if you are looping incorrectly. Or just try commenting out the `if` and/or the `else` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
split(image, Bands);
```

You will get from a CV_8UC3 image (`image`) 3 CV_8U images (`Bands`). Everything is good until this point. Then you go to your adjusting and do 2 mistakes:

1. `Mat adjustedBand;` is never initialized... You can do `Mat adjustedBand(band.rows, band.cols, CV_8UC1);` or intialized in a later stage.
2. `pixel = band.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];` and `adjustedBand.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = temp;` are for manipulating 3 channels not a 1 channel image. You need to use `uchar`instead, like: `adjustedBand.at<uchar>(i,j) = temp;`

Those are the errors I see... fix them and try using a debugger, that way you know if something is initialize correctly or if it does the correct operation